# Selecting the sibling of the active or focus element using CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, dom, browser

I am trying to implement button like features to show and hide errors using CSS.

When the user clicks the CSS button or link, I am able to select the siblings of the focused element as below.  This only works in IE8+.

```
#ShowErrors:focus + a + a + a + div ul li.Error{
    display: list-item;
}
```

But focus is not supported in IE7.  :active does not work.  Only hover seems to work in selecting siblings.  But, I want to achieve a button like behavior.  Is this possible using only CSS in IE 7?  #ShowErrors is a link ().

Comment: If you so much as think about using such a selector... Just don't.

Comment: Back away from the Commodore 64, please.

Comment: that's the longest css selector I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a polyfill to achieve the `:focus` functionality in older browsers. I recommend [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) since it is widely supported and tested. It is also available in several frameworks, which makes it fit easier into your production environment.

Regarding the sibling selector, this is [supported back to IE6](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2). So unless you are trying to go that far back, I wouldn't worry about that one.

Comment: Unfortunately, JS is not available.